# which rpc endpoint is used to find the roll snapshot which was used for determining baking/endorsing rights at a certain cycle?

Tags: node, rpc

I would like to know, for every baker at cycle x, how many rolls they owned that contributed to their baking rights in that cycle. To do that, I believe I have to know how many rolls they owned during the particular snapshot that was selected in cycle x - 7. Is there any way to get this number from a full archival node?

Answer (score 4):

You can get information about snapshot for a given cycle from the raw context:

```
var cycle = 100;
var level = cycle * 4096 + 1;

var snapshot = get('/chains/main/blocks/{level}/context/raw/json/cycle/{cycle}/roll_snapshot');

var snapshot_block = ((cycle - 7) * 4096 + 1) + (snapshot + 1) * 256 - 1;

var balance = get('/chains/main/blocks/{snapshot_block}/context/contracts/KT1.../balance');
```

Comment: In the definition of _snapshot\_block_ I think it should be  (snapshot - 1)  instead of  (snapshot + 1)

Comment: I'm afraid you're wrong ;) Did you try to check it?

Comment: yes I was wrong the snapshot index ranges from 0 to 15 but there is a -1 after * 256.

Comment: (this is funny there is a 5 min limit to post a comment), anyway for example for the first snapshot cycle with blocks range {1 - 4096}, the first snapshot is taken at block 256, then the second at 512 and so on. That means that the snapshot_block equation is ((7 - 7) *4096 +1) + (snap + 1) *256 -1. With snap={0,1} we have snapshot_block={256,512}  (I checked on tzscan.io)

Comment: Hmm, I have looked at the sources https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/proto_alpha/lib_protocol/apply.ml#L968 and found that the whole time was wrong... Thanks a lot!

Comment: This seems kind of important to get right. Direct evidence from the chain seems possible?

Comment: it can be a bit confusing but the earlier snapshot eq. was only incorrectly shifted by 1 block, it would have been a problem only if a delegation was added/removed 1 block before the actual snapshot block. Here a couple of useful rpc. The first shows the first-last block of a particular cycle: ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/head/helpers/levels_in_current_cycle?"offset=<-some#>" 
the next rpc shows the snapshot number: ./tezos-client rpc get /chains/main/blocks/<some_block>/context/raw/json/cycle/<some_cycle>/roll_snapshot (<some_block> can be any block within the first-last range)